# How can I save inputs from Python Tkinter into a txt file?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import END
from typing import  *
from tkinter import Tk
import tweepy
import time



window = Tk()
window.title("Tweetio")
window.minsize(1000,800)
top_frame = Frame(window).pack()
bottom_frame = Frame(window).pack()
btns_frame = Frame(window, pady = 10)
btns_frame.pack()


def openKey():
    
    newwin = Toplevel(window)
    newwin.title('Insert API Key')
    newwin.geometry('500x250')
    newwin.resizable(0, 0)
    newwin.columnconfigure(0, pad=3)
    newwin.columnconfigure(1, pad=3)
    newwin.rowconfigure(0, pad=6)
    newwin.rowconfigure(1, pad=6)
    newwin.rowconfigure(2, pad=6)
    newwin.rowconfigure(3, pad=6)
    newwin.rowconfigure(4, pad=6)
    Label(newwin, text = "API KEY:").grid(row = 0)
    Label(newwin, text = "API KEY SECRET:").grid(row = 1)
    Label(newwin, text = "BEARER TOKEN:").grid(row = 2)
    Label(newwin, text = "ACCESS TOKEN:").grid(row = 3)
    Label(newwin, text = "ACCESS TOKEN SECRET:").grid(row = 4)
    api_key = Entry(newwin).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    api_secret_key = Entry(newwin).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    bearer_token = Entry(newwin).grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    access_token = Entry(newwin).grid(row = 3, column = 1)
    access_token_secret = Entry(newwin).grid(row = 4, column = 1)
     
     
    def saveEntry(): 
        with open ('api_keys.text', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(input(api_key) + '\n')
            f.write(input(api_secret_key) + '\n')
            f.write(input(bearer_token) + '\n')
            f.write(input(access_token) + '\n')
            f.write(input(access_token_secret) + '\n')

    Button(newwin, text = "Enter", width = 30, height = 5, pady = 10, fg = "Black", bg = "Gold", command = lambda:saveEntry).grid(row = 8, column = 1)
```

I'm trying to save the user input into a txt file to be used later in the program. I want to save all 5 inputs into the same txt folder. Then, call back on the text file with 'r'. It's tkinter for Python. Any ideas? Any input would be much appreciated.

I tried to use 'w' and f.write but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

First, the `Entry` widgets are not being assigned to variables properly, so you will not be able to retrieve their values. Use code below instead:

```
api_key = Entry(newwin)
api_key.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
```

In addition, you should use the `get` method on the `Entry` widgets instead of `input` to retrieve the user input through the `Entry` widgets, like this:

```
api_key_value = api_key.get()
```

along with this:

```
with open ('api_keys.text', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(api_key_value + '\n')
    ...
```

Hope this could help.